# Jenkins not recognizing alias ssh for my github repo

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, ssh-keys, webhooks

My server had already a jenkins setup for a project with its corresponding ssh key. However, I'm developing a new (separate) project and I'm trying to integrate it with Jenkins CI.

I had to create a ssh alias and it works like a charm. I tested cloning the repo from the jenkins user on the server and everything works. However, when I send a test from my github's service webhook I get the following on my Jenkins' logs:

> Could not match URL user@alias:xxx/project.git

Any ideas on how to make the alias work with jenkins + github?

Comment: Do you use any github webhook jenkin pluins?

Comment: Im using GitHub Plugin in Jenkins

Comment: Corresponding issue: [JENKINS-18298 Jenkins (Github Plugin) post-commit hook fails to build with ssh config aliases](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18298)

Answer (score 0):

To use alias, do you setup the `~/.ssh/config` file like this ?

```
Host alias
HostName github.com
User user
IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: This wouldn't work when using deploy keys on a repository level (i.e. different keys for each repo with r/w access to only one particular repo). In that case the alias needs to be more specific, e.g. `HostName foo.github.com`, `HostName bar.github.com`, to reference different identity files, which leads to repo address sent with the hook event not matching up in Jenkins.